# Apache CXF - None of the policy alternatives can be satisfied Exception

Tags: java, web-services, cxf, wsdl2java

I'm implementing a webservice client for this https://efactura.dgi.gub.uy:6470/ePrueba/ws_personaGetActEmpresarialPrueba?wsdl   3rd-party wsdl.

I generated the java clases using apache-cxf-3.0.4 wsdl2java.

The endpoint need to be signed using ws-security with X.509 Certificates signature. To address that I configure some Out interceptors but I  get an "None of the policy alternatives can be satisfied" Exception.

Here is the code that configures the interceptor and do de soap call:

```
Map<String, Object> outProps = new HashMap<String, Object>();
outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.ACTION, WSHandlerConstants.SIGNATURE + " " + WSHandlerConstants.TIMESTAMP);
outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.SIGNATURE_PARTS, "");
outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.USER, "<aliasCertName>");
outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.PW_CALLBACK_CLASS, ClientCallbackHandler.class.getName());
outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.SIG_PROP_FILE, "client_sign.properties");
outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.SIGNATURE_PARTS, "{Element}{http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/v1.2/ws-securitypolicy-1.2.xsd}SignedParts;{Element}{http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd}Timestamp;{Element}{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Body;");
outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.ENCRYPTION_PARTS, "{http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#}Signature;{Content}{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Body");
outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.ENC_PROP_FILE, "client_sign.properties");


/*
* Create service, port and send the request
*/
ObjectFactory objectFactory = new ObjectFactory();
WSPersonaGetActEmpresarialExecute req = objectFactory.createWSPersonaGetActEmpresarialExecute();
req.setRut("21047573001133");
WSPersonaGetActEmpresarial service = new WSPersonaGetActEmpresarial();
WSPersonaGetActEmpresarialSoapPort port = service.getWSPersonaGetActEmpresarialSoapPort();

//Obtain a reference to the CXF endpoint using the ClientProxy helper:
Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(wsPersonaGetActEmpresarialSoapPort);
client.getOutInterceptors().add(new WSS4JOutInterceptor(outProps));


WSPersonaGetActEmpresarialExecuteResponse response = port.execute(req);
```

And the exception:

```
03:07:26.227 [main] WARN  o.a.c.w.p.AssertionBuilderRegistryImpl - No assertion builder for type {http://www.datapower.com/extensions}summary registered.
03:07:26.229 [main] WARN  o.a.c.w.p.AssertionBuilderRegistryImpl - No assertion builder for type {http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200512}SignedParts registered.
03:07:26.232 [main] DEBUG o.a.cxf.ws.policy.PolicyEngineImpl - Alternative {http://www.datapower.com/extensions}summary is not supported
03:07:26.233 [main] DEBUG o.a.cxf.ws.policy.PolicyEngineImpl - Alternative {http://www.datapower.com/extensions}summary is not supported
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: None of the policy alternatives can be satisfied.
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:161)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy33.execute(Unknown Source)
    at tests.consultaPorRUT.main(consultaPorRUT.java:150)
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.PolicyException: None of the policy alternatives can be satisfied.
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.EndpointPolicyImpl.chooseAlternative(EndpointPolicyImpl.java:172)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.EndpointPolicyImpl.finalizeConfig(EndpointPolicyImpl.java:146)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.EndpointPolicyImpl.initialize(EndpointPolicyImpl.java:142)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.PolicyEngineImpl.createEndpointPolicyInfo(PolicyEngineImpl.java:584)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.PolicyEngineImpl.getEndpointPolicy(PolicyEngineImpl.java:313)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.PolicyEngineImpl.getClientEndpointPolicy(PolicyEngineImpl.java:294)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.PolicyDataEngineImpl.getClientEndpointPolicy(PolicyDataEngineImpl.java:61)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.updateClientPolicy(HTTPConduit.java:318)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.updateClientPolicy(HTTPConduit.java:338)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.getClient(HTTPConduit.java:855)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.configureConduitFromEndpointInfo(HTTPConduit.java:360)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.finalizeConfig(HTTPConduit.java:440)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPTransportFactory.getConduit(HTTPTransportFactory.java:242)
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapTransportFactory.getConduit(SoapTransportFactory.java:222)
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapTransportFactory.getConduit(SoapTransportFactory.java:229)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.AbstractConduitSelector.createConduit(AbstractConduitSelector.java:145)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.AbstractConduitSelector.getSelectedConduit(AbstractConduitSelector.java:107)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.UpfrontConduitSelector.prepare(UpfrontConduitSelector.java:63)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.prepareConduitSelector(ClientImpl.java:849)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:509)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:423)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:324)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:277)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:96)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:139)
    ... 2 more
```

How do I need to address this error?

Answer (score 0):

When there is a security policy in the WSDL, you use a different way of configuring WS-Security. You are configuring WS-Security via the "action" based approach. However, looking at the WSDL, the policy is not standard. So you might be better keeping your current configuration, but write an interceptor for the client code to assert the relevant policies.

Answer (score 0):

As i can see from the exception.It seems like you have configured too many token systems like **username token profile** , **x509v3 token certificates** , **saml token** etc or **atleast one of them** /and none of them match with the provider policies[provider has configured more than one token systems credentials for all his clients]. Your configuration must match atleast with one of the Providers recommended credentials tokens like username token and x509 token certificates so that you can access the service[i think runtime will determine which policies intersect].